# Generate custom Json from an object Array

Tags: javascript, json, typescript-types

I'm trying to generate a json from an array of objects using the `JSON.stringify()` funtion.
The structure of the array is the following one:

```
export interface FilledCells {
  floor?: number;
  coordinates: {
    x: number;
    y: number;
  };
  type: string | undefined;
  seat: number;
  bikeSize?: string;
  group: string;
}
```

Using the `JSON.stringify(array)` function will produce this result:

```
[
 {
  "floor": 0,
  "coordinates": {
   "x": 23,
   "y": 1
  },
  "type": "regular",
  "seat": 2,
  "group": "A"
 },
 {
  "floor": 0,
  "coordinates": {
   "x": 24,
   "y": 1
  },
  "type": "premium",
  "seat": 1,
  "group": "A"
 }
]
```

Now my question is, how can I customuize this json structure before sending it to the back end? I need to add a field at the begginning called "layout" and also each object should be contained in an array called "seats".
What I'm trying to obtain is something like this:

```
"seatingConfiguration": [
            {
                "layout": "regular",
                "seats": [
                {
                    "floor": 0,
                    "coordinates": {
                         "x": 23,
                         "y": 1
                     },
                    "type": "regular",
                    "seat": 2,
                    "group": "A"
                },
                {
                    "floor": 0,
                    "coordinates": {
                         "x": 24,
                         "y": 1
                     },
                    "type": "premium",
                    "seat": 1,
                    "group": "A"
                }
                ]
            },
        ]
```

Thank you :)

Comment: Convert back to object with `JSON.parse` and add whatever you want to in-memory object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you need?

```js
const array = [
    {
        floor: 0,
        coordinates: {
            x: 23,
            y: 1
        },
        type: "regular",
        seat: 2,
        group: "A"
    },
    {
        floor: 0,
        coordinates: {
            x: 24,
            y: 1
        },
        type: "premium",
        seat: 1,
        group: "A"
    }
]

const jsonstring = JSON.stringify({
    seatingConfiguration: [
        {
            layout: "regular",
            seats: array
        }
    ]
})

console.log(jsonstring)

console.log(JSON.parse(jsonstring))
```